# How To Import Module From Top Level Directory in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-module

I have the following directory structure:

```
top/
    mod1.py
    pkg1/
        mod2.py
```

The goal is to import objects from `mod1.py` inside the `mod2.py` file, Eventually I might have to use more complicated figures, like if there had been another directory with other modules on the `mod1.py` file level, but in neither of the 2 cases am I being able to import the required objects (inside `mod2.py`):

```
from ..mod1 import *
```

,

```
from .mod1 import *
```

I'm using `Python 3.8.0`,
Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Comment: What do you mean by "not able to import the required objects"? Do you get an error? Do the objects fail to show up?

Comment: Depends, gives me: ```no module name```, or ```attempted to relative import with not known parent package```.

Comment: @effy Thanks, so far ```sys.path.append('../')``` solved the problem; it's still not perfect, the best would be, imo, to not messing with ```PATH```; but it allows me to keep going though.